# How to parse an array to return a collection?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a certain model in the form of a structure:

```
struct ContactsModel {
  let name: String
  let status: String
  let number: String
  let onlineStatus: Bool
}
```

And there is a method that parses the array of names and adds them to the new collection.

```
    var contactsDictionary = [String: [String]]()
    var contactNameSectionTitles = [String]()
    var names = [String]()
    var contactsArray = [ContactsModel(name: "Test", status: "Test", number: "+7 999 999 99 99", onlineStatus: true)]

    func configurateDictionary() {
        names = contactsArray.map {$0.name}

        for value in names {
            let nameKey = String(value.prefix(1))

            if var namePrefix = contactsDictionary[nameKey] {
                namePrefix.append(value)
                contactsDictionary[nameKey] = namePrefix
            } else {
                contactsDictionary[nameKey] = [value]
            }
        }

        contactNameSectionTitles = [String](contactsDictionary.keys)
        contactNameSectionTitles = contactNameSectionTitles.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
    }
```

How do I do so in the method so that it returns not a string, but a model? I want the collection to be type

```
var contactsDictionary = [String: [ContactsModel]]()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init) to group an array to a dictionary

```
var contactsDictionary = [String:[ContactsModel]]()
var contactNameSectionTitles = [String]()


func configurateDictionary() {
    contactsDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: contactsArray, by: { $0.prefix(1).uppercased() })
    contactNameSectionTitles = contactsDictionary.keys.sorted()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need Dictionary grouping by , e.x to group the array by name do

```
let arr = [ContactsModel]
let res = Dictionary(grouping: arr, by: { $0.name }) // [String:[ContactsModel]]
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init

Comment: This is not exactly what I need. I want to change the 'func configurateDictionary ()' method to return a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

This method will return a dictionary of `[String: ContactsModel]`

```
func configurateDictionary() -> [String: ContactsModel] {
    let result = contactsArray.reduce( [String: ContactsModel](), { (d, e) -> [String: ContactsModel] in 
        var dict = d
        dict[e.name] = e 
        return dict
    })        
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the `configurateDictionary` method to return `[String: [ContactsModel]]`, create a temporary dictionary inside the function and return it at the end of the function

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var contactsDictionary = [String: [ContactsModel]]()
    var contactNameSectionTitles = [String]()
    var names = [String]()
    var contactsArray = [ContactsModel(name: "Test", status: "Test", number: "+7 999 999 99 99", onlineStatus: true)]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        contactsDictionary = configurateDictionary()
    }
    func configurateDictionary() -> [String: [ContactsModel]] {
        names.removeAll()
        contactNameSectionTitles.removeAll()
        var temp = [String: [ContactsModel]]()
        for contact in contactsArray {
            names.append(contact.name)
            let nameKey = String(contact.name.prefix(1))
            temp[nameKey, default: []].append(contact)
        }
        contactNameSectionTitles = [String](contactsDictionary.keys).sorted()
        return temp
    }
}
```